# How to specify string padding with a variable in Python 2.5?

Tags: python

For example:

```
print('items %05d'%12)
```

would print 00012.

Can the amount of padding be specified by a variable instead of a literal?  I believe python 2.6+ has the .format function but what are the options with python 2.5?

Comment: copying the headline into google, first hit, then search for padd, leads to `rjust`, use as `num_digits = 5; print str(12).rjust(num_digits,'0')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the width number with a `*` and the Python `%` substitution will expect an integer value, and use that for the width.  Since you will now have at least two values for the `%` operator (one width and one actual value) you will need to make a tuple to pass them together.

```
print "items %0*d" % (5, 12)
```

If you leave out the `0` before the `*` you will get padding with spaces rather than `0`.

Documented here:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html

Section 3.6.2, rule 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> '##%*s##' % (3, '$')
'##  $##'
```

Answer (score 0):

For more modern versions of Python 3.x try this:

```py
python -c 'print(f"{2**32:,}".rjust(16))'
   4,294,967,296
```